# Angular2 Router Hates My AUX Routes

Tags: javascript, angular, router

**UPDATE 11/1/15**

Aux Routes are not supported very well as of Alpha 45.
[Link to Github Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4945)

props to @evan-plaice

**Original Question**

I watched Brian Ford's talk on the Angular2 Router:https://youtu.be/z1NB-HG0ZH4

And I started to try and use the "Aux" routes and my code is throwing a ton of errors.

I'm on **Alpha 44** on [mgechev's Angular Seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed)

In my app.ts component it's pretty standard, for the `RouteConfig` I Have:

```js
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/', component: HomeCmp, as: 'Home' },
  { path: '/run', component: RunCmp, as: 'Run' },
  { path: '/manage', component: ManageCmp, as: 'Manage' },
  { path: '/user', component: UserCmp, as: 'User' },
  { path: '/settings', component: LocalSettingsCmp, as: 'Settings' },
  { aux: '/login', component: LoginCmp, as: 'Login' }
])
```

My app.html:

```
<div id="main-content" class="full">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <router-outlet name="login"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Inside the **HomeCmp** I put a "Login" Link:

```js
<p>Router Link to activate login form: <a [router-link]="['/',['Login']]">Login</a></p>
```

Now I have other router links in that component that work fine, but when I add this link gives me this error:

Exception:

```
EXCEPTION: "/" is only allowed at the beginning of a link DSL. in [null]
BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js?v=0.0.0:21835
BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @ angular2.dev.js?v=0.0.0:21846
ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.dev.js?v=0.0.0:4431
(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js?v=0.0.0:19543
NgZone._onError @ angular2.dev.js?v=0.0.0:10711
errorHandling.onError @ angular2.dev.js?v=0.0.0:10630
run @ angular2.dev.js?v=0.0.0:141
(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js?v=0.0.0:10651
zoneBoundFn @ angular2.dev.js?v=0.0.0:111
lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush @ angular2.dev.js?v=0.0.0:1301
angular2.dev.js?v=0.0.0:21835
```

Error:

```
Error: "/" is only allowed at the beginning of a link DSL.
    at new BaseException (http://localhost:5555/lib/angular2.dev.js?v=0.0.0:16034:21)
    at RouteRegistry.generate (http://localhost:5555/lib/router.dev.js?v=0.0.0:1645:17)
    at ChildRouter.Router.generate (http://localhost:5555/lib/router.dev.js?v=0.0.0:2044:43)
    at RouterLink.Object.defineProperty.set [as routeParams] (http://localhost:5555/lib/router.dev.js?v=0.0.0:1323:52)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.ChangeDetector_HomeCmp_0.detectChangesInRecordsInternal (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5555/lib/angular2.dev.js?v=0.0.0:20415:14), <anonymous>:118:40)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.detectChangesInRecords (http://localhost:5555/lib/angular2.dev.js?v=0.0.0:20209:14)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.runDetectChanges (http://localhost:5555/lib/angular2.dev.js?v=0.0.0:20192:12)
    at AbstractChangeDetector._detectChangesInShadowDomChildren (http://localhost:5555/lib/angular2.dev.js?v=0.0.0:20259:14)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.runDetectChanges (http://localhost:5555/lib/angular2.dev.js?v=0.0.0:20196:12)
    at AbstractChangeDetector._detectChangesInLightDomChildren (http://localhost:5555/lib/angular2.dev.js?v=0.0.0:20253:14)
```

Context:

```
{element: a, componentElement: home, context: HomeCmp, locals: Object, injector: Injector…}
```

It Also throws this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'child' of undefined
    at ChildRouter.Router.isRouteActive (http://localhost:5555/lib/router.dev.js?v=0.0.0:1803:77)
    at RouterLink.Object.defineProperty.get [as isRouteActive] (http://localhost:5555/lib/router.dev.js?v=0.0.0:1315:29)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.ChangeDetector_HomeCmp_0.detectChangesInRecordsInternal (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5555/lib/angular2.dev.js?v=0.0.0:20415:14), <anonymous>:153:44)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.detectChangesInRecords (http://localhost:5555/lib/angular2.dev.js?v=0.0.0:20209:14)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.runDetectChanges (http://localhost:5555/lib/angular2.dev.js?v=0.0.0:20192:12)
    at AbstractChangeDetector._detectChangesInShadowDomChildren (http://localhost:5555/lib/angular2.dev.js?v=0.0.0:20259:14)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.runDetectChanges (http://localhost:5555/lib/angular2.dev.js?v=0.0.0:20196:12)
    at AbstractChangeDetector._detectChangesInLightDomChildren (http://localhost:5555/lib/angular2.dev.js?v=0.0.0:20253:14)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.runDetectChanges (http://localhost:5555/lib/angular2.dev.js?v=0.0.0:20193:12)
    at AbstractChangeDetector._detectChangesInShadowDomChildren (http://localhost:5555/lib/angular2.dev.js?v=0.0.0:20259:14)
```

But it's after the first error so I'm not sure if its caused by the first or what.

I also tried the [Way from the Angular2 API Docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/AuxRoute-class.html)
but it throws the same errors.

- Am I doing something wrong?
- Is this syntax not supported yet?
- Is there an example of someone using the Aux Routes Correctly?

*NOTE: I tried getting the Router to work with a Plunker but it doesnt like the URL's or something otherwise I'd provide a live case*

**UPDATE 10/29/15**
The first error is from the router link not letting you use "\" or ".\" in any way. You MUST specify the route name.

Aux still does not work...

Answer (score 3):

**The routerLink matches the path of the first parameter in the array**

In your case it would match `/` or `Home`

```
<a [routerLink]="['/',['Login']]">Login</a>
```

*Use this instead:*

```
<a [routerLink]="['/Login']">Login</a>
```

AFAIK, the parameter is an array because a route can also include one-or-more wildcard matches.

*Note: The `Login` used in the link points to the route's alias (ie the `as` field).*

*Source:*

- [angular2/src/router/router_link.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/router/router_link.ts)

**Update:**

Keep an eye out. The angular2 team is planning to change `RouterLink`/`<router-link>` to `RouterViewport`/`<router-viewport>` in a future release.

*Source: [angular/issues#4679](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4679)*

**Update2:**

- [router-link] -> [routerLink]

Comment: I believe they are changing `<router-outlet>` not `<router-link>`

Comment: So your link is correct for a **standard** router link, but when using multiple outlets and the "Aux" link they show using an array as the second parameter to specify the name of the aux. Which doesn't work... The intent is to have multiple `<router-outlet>` 's on a component but it isn't working for me. My use case is for a login/register form which is the example from the talk...

Comment: Yeah... I realized that after the fact. Looks like they're still working on it https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4319

Comment: "There is no way currently to generate urls for auxiliary routes" https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4945

Comment: Ok so the issue is Aux routes simply don't work at the moment... I was thinking I was doing something wrong... Good find @evan-plaice

Comment: The last link I posted did show a way to link to them from the controller ex. `router.navigateByUrl('/guestbook(side)');`. If you're just experimenting, that might give you a means to get started.